# SQL Query Execution time , SQL Server, Nested Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, execution, sqlperformance

I have a query as following:

`SELECT Brand,Id,Model FROM product`

Which takes time in order of seconds as Product table has more than 1 million records.

But the query executes within no time. (less than even one second))

`select count(*) as numberOfRows from (SELECT Brand,Id,Model FROM product) result`

Why is that?

Comment: Probably because the query optimizer sees that your query can be optimized to get only the number of records and not all records itself. BTW you normally do it like this: `SELECT count(*) FROM product`

Comment: Because sql server is intelligent enough to notice you are not actually doing anything with the selected columns, so it just executes a `count(*)`. Check the execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a Query, the Time taken will vary depending on the Number of Columns and Rows and their datatypes.

In a table where you have 10 Columns, The Performance will be different if you select all columns (*) for all records and Just 1 or Two Columns for All records.
Because The Amount of data loaded is less in the Second case, it will execute faster.

Just like that, When you say Count(*) the result is Just a single Cell whereas in your first Select, you are selecting Millions of rows for those 3 columns, So the amount of Data is high.

That's why you are getting the Count(*) result faster. You don't need to give * inside the count, Instead Just use Count(1) for even more better performance.

Comment: Although what you say might apply to marginal performance issues, it really has nothing to do with the question.  And `count(*)` and `count(1)` have the same performance.